# How do I recursively display all files and subfolders?

Tags: alfresco

I'm using the [Alfresco Rest Api](https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/) but I can't find any option that would return the whole tree with all sub-folders.

I want to go down to the last file even if it's 'wrapped' in 3 sub folders.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can.

You could execute a PATH query though, since it can be written in a way to return all children, too.

For example:

```
var folder = search.luceneSearch("+PATH:\"/app:company_home/cm:Test_x0020_Folder//*\" AND (TYPE:\"cm:content\" OR TYPE:\"cm:folder\")");
```

Answer (score 2):

Please refer `categoryService` to list all files in any nested sub folders. Here 
`nodeRef` is parent folder's noderef

Using categoryService it is also possible to list all the children of a folder.

```
Collection<ChildAssociationRef> children = categoryService.getChildren(new NodeRef(nodeRef), CategoryService.Mode.ALL, CategoryService.Depth.ANY);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a java baked webscript which will return the node of below object.

```
public class ReportNode {

    private NodeRef currentNode;
    private List<ReportNode> children;
    private Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
    private boolean isFolder;
    private String name;
    private String type;
    private List<String> aspects;
//Getter Setters
}
```

In above structure 
**currentNode** represents the current nodered in list
**children** represents the children of a node

Other things are well understood.

Fill up the data in above linked list structure by node crawling.

For displaying the crawled data.You can use the below freemarker template.

```
<#macro recurse_macro nodeRef>
    <ul>
        <li> 
                <@print_properties reportNode=nodeRef/>
        </li>
     </ul>
</#macro>

<#macro print_properties reportNode>
        <ul>
            <li> 
                <a>Properties</a>
                    <ul>
                        <#list reportNode.properties?keys as key> 
                                        <li>${key} : ${reportNode.properties[key]}
                        </#list>

                    </ul>
            </li>
         </ul>
</#macro>

<@recurse_macro nodeRef=nodeRef/>
```

where noderef is root node of the linked list which is created by crawling the nodes.

Comment: Thank you but I have no idea what this is, I just use the REST api.

Comment: There is not rest api available which will give the response as per your requirement, so you need to develop one.From your comment , i guess you are not alfresco developer so first learn how to develop a webscript in alfresco.This link will help you in that http://www.krutikjayswal.com/2016/10/alfresco-webscript-spring-webscript.html

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve all documents you can use this service

[http://localhost:8080/share/service/components/documentlibrary/data/doclist/all/site/XXXX/documentLibrary?filter=all&noCache=1521477198549](http://localhost:8080/share/service/components/documentlibrary/data/doclist/all/site/averroes/documentLibrary?filter=all&noCache=1521477198549)

Or you can create your custom webscript and get nodes recursively like that for example:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param type
 * @param nodeRef
 * @return true if node type equals or inherit from type <code>type</code>
 */
protected boolean hasSubType(QName type, NodeRef nodeRef) {
    List<QName> subTypes = new ArrayList<>();
    subTypes.addAll(dictionaryService.getSubTypes(type, true));
    QName nodeType = nodeService.getType(nodeRef);
    return nodeType.equals(type) || subTypes.contains(nodeType);
}

private void getNodesRecursive(NodeRef node, List<NodeRef> documents) {
    if (hasSubType(ContentModel.TYPE_FOLDER, node)) {
        List<ChildAssociationRef> children = nodeService.getChildAssocs(node, ContentModel.ASSOC_CONTAINS, RegexQNamePattern.MATCH_ALL);
        for (ChildAssociationRef child : children) {
            NodeRef childNode = child.getChildRef();
            if (hasSubType(ContentModel.TYPE_CONTENT, node)) {
                documents.add(childNode);
            } else if (hasSubType(ContentModel.TYPE_FOLDER, node)) {
                // documents.add(childNode);
                getNodesRecursive(childNode, documents);
            }
        }
    } else {
        documents.add(node);
    }
}
```